# vb.net: is it possible to comment out more than 1 line of code at a time?

Tags: vb.net

i know in java and other nice languages it's possible to comment out a bunch of lines at the same time. is it possible to do this in vb.net?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you mean syntactically, like `/* ... */` in C++, then no. But if you mean from your IDE, then from Visual Studio:

- Highlight the text you want to comment out
- Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- You can also *uncomment* text using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

Answer (score 8):

You can use conditional compilation  to achieve the same effect:

```
#If False Then

Dim parameters() As SqlParameter = _
{ _
    New SqlParameter("@program_year", programYear), _
    New SqlParameter("@report_id", reportId), _
    New SqlParameter("@report_group", reportGroup), _
    New SqlParameter("@report_period", reportPeriod) _
}
Return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataSet(Report.ConnectionString, kSql, parameters, CommandType.StoredProcedure)

#End If
```

Comment: This is better in many ways than the CTRLK CTRKC method as the code is not really a "comment", but code you don't want to compile right now.  It is greyed out rather than green on VS2012.

Answer (score 5):

Yup.  Select the text and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.  And you can uncomment it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not you need to comment out each line individually

Answer (score 0):

If you edit VB in emacs, you just do M-x comment-region.