# multiline comment in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, comments

Do we have a multi line comment in VB.net.
I know in Java we have /* */ but that doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: This is also a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909447/vb-net-is-it-possible-to-comment-out-more-than-1-line-of-code-at-a-time  Please first use the search before asking the same question.

Comment: there is ..  see below my answer

Answer (score 52, accepted):

No we dont unfortunately..........

You can do: Ctrl + K, Crtl + C

To uncomment ctrl+k ctrl+u

Comment: @krum_cho highlight what you want to comment and then ctrl +k and ctrl+c to comment.  No other way around it.

Comment: What if I don't use VB Studio and use notepad ++ instead ?

Comment: If you don't use VBStudio, you will need to make a macro up in Notepad++ or manually comment out each line.

Answer (score 14):

In Visual Basic .Net 2008 and 2010, I use the following C++ Workaround.

`#If AFAC Then`

`#End if`

For English speaking AFAC = "à effacer" = "to delete"

I already use `#If COMMENT` or `#If TODO`

The **#if COMMENT then** solution is more powerful than the C++/Java/C# `/* text */` solution because it is possible to nest `#if` but not `/*` !!!

For more information see the following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx6yas69%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: More generally, you should be able to do `#If 0 Then` ... `#End if` to comment things out. (And put any text after `//`).

Comment: why complicate? just use `#If False Then`.

Comment: I tried the #if approach, (VB.Net 2017). The problem is intellisense still kicks in within the #if block and interferes with your typing.

Answer (score 6):

Just hold "alt"+"shift" and move cursor up or down to select lines, and press " ' "

Comment: WHOA i had no idea you could do that!

Answer (score 3):

you can do on all visual studio version ..

```
#Region "mycomment"
 'comment line1
 'comment line2
#End Region
```

you will be able to hide and show the entire block

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not possible.
Write your chunk, select it and press Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C to comment it.

But it doesn't always matter as often you use ''' in front of a method or property to describe it. Then it will automatically create the comments for you.

Answer (score 1):

Only single-line comments are possible in VB, unlike C/C++ and it's derivatives (Java, JavaScript, C#, etc.). You can use the apostrophe " ' " or REM (remark) for comments like this:

```
Sub Main()  
    ' This is a comment  
    REM This is also a comment  
End Sub
```

But there is no multi-line comment operator in VB, unless you count using the keyboard shortcuts like @JonH and @Tedd Hansen
 said.

Comment: Sorry, but the #if AFAC that I describe previously do the same thing that /* */.