# Comment out inline if statement in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I am having problems trying to comment out an inline if statement in VB.  Is this even possible?  This syntax does not seem to be recognized in Visual Studio.

```
'IIf(BusinessFactor <> 1, " x Business Factor " & BusinessFactor& " = $" & brPremium & " (rounded)", "") & _
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909447/vb-net-is-it-possible-to-comment-out-more-than-1-line-of-code-at-a-time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your inline If-statement has a *line continuation character* (which is the underscore `_`) after it, which means that the whole statement continues on the next line.

You would need to put that continuation char before the comment, but as that is not possible (due to that the continuation character must be the last on that line) your only option is to (re)move the entire If.

In cases where you don't have a continuation character, commenting it out will work just fine.

Comment: Or you could just comment the following line. Note also that recent versions of VB.NET have relaxed the cases where a line-continuation character is required, so it may be possible to omit it altogether. Of course, you'll still have a compilation error because the continued line doesn't make sense with the initial line commented-out.

Comment: Appreciate the help.  I am just going to remove the line.  The reason for the continuation is that it is part of a large calculation string.  I am not a fan of how it was written but I am just "maintaining" the code.